# WxPython 3.0 installation in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wxpython, ubuntu-14.04, kicad

I am trying to build KiCad on Ubintu 14.04 where i need to install wxPython 3.0 . But the problem is that I am not able to install wxPython 3.0. Moreover, i am unable to find any help to install this package. Plese help me to sortout this issue. Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install these packages from the KiCad PPA at https://launchpad.net/~js-reynaud/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-kicad?field.series_filter=trusty

Comment: Hi dear, I have used adam's ppa to inetall these packages and these packages were install succesfully. the link is given below. 

https://launchpad.net/~adamwolf/+archive/ubuntu/kicad-trusty-backports